# Newton's cubic curve

Tags: plotting

This [article](http://www.theguardian.com/science/alexs-adventures-in-numberland/2017/may/01/the-colour-of-numbers-visions-of-our-mathematical-universe) from *The Guardian* discusses Isaac Newton's investigation of the properties of the curve $x^3 – abx + a^3 – cy^2 = 0$, where $a, b$ and $c$ are constants. The image above is the curve of this equation when $a = 1, c = 4$ and $b$ ranges from –8 to 8.

The image seemsextremely aesthetic to me , almost artistic work. I'd have image on the wall like a poster, but with

```
ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@Table[x^3 + b x == 4 y^2, {b, -8, 8, 1}], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  Frame -> None, ImageSize -> 600,  ContourStyle -> Black, PlotPoints -> 20]
```

I can not reproduce that image. The result is a bit different. Can someone please explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Well, you seem to have done your substitutions incorrectly. The correct equation you should plot is `x^3 - b x - 4 y^2 + 1 == 0`. You are missing a constant, and the `b x` term seems to have the wrong sign. If you change the equation to the one I showed, the plots is much more similar to the one in the link. You might also want to restrict the range of `x` to e.g. `{x, -5, 3.5}`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know how I managed to make such a ridiculous mistake.

Answer (score 7):

You are plotting wrong equation, See this.

```
a = 1; c = 4;
ContourPlot[
Evaluate@Table[x^3 - a*b *x + a^3 - c*y^2 == 0, {b, -8, 8, 0.5}], {x, -3., 
3.}, {y, -3.5, 3.5}, Frame -> None, ImageSize -> 600, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.0015],PlotPoints -> 20]
```

I have changed the step size of $b$ and plot range of axis to mimic with the figure in that link.

It plots as: 
[image]

Comment: You can maintain sharpness while increasing the number of steps (`{b, -8, 8, 1/2}`) by using `ContourStyle -> Directive[Thin, Black]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, Modified, Thank you